# C# - How to send string to url in window phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I create method in a static class (window phone) :

```
public  void testSend()
      {
          try
          {
              string url = "";
              string str = "test";
              HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
              req.Method = "POST";
              string Data = "data=" + str;
              byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
              req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
              req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
              Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
              requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
              requestStream.Close();

              HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
              Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

              var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
              string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();


          }
          catch (WebException)
          {

          }
```

I'm not sure but it get error on GetRequestStream() and GetResponse because it does not contain in HttpWebRequest.Please help me.

Comment: you have set `url` to "" thats why it is throwing error

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WebClient or HttpWebRequest.

Exemple with web client =>

```
    public void testSend()
  {
              string url = "";
              string str = "test";
              HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
              req.Method = "POST";
              string Data = "data=" + str;
              byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
              req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
              req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
              Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
              requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
              requestStream.Close();

              HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
              Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

              var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
              string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
              WebClient client = new WebClient();
              client.UploadStringCompleted += client_UploadStringCompleted;
              client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), responseText);

  }

void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // error in uploading
    }
}
```

Comment: But it get error :'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetRequestStream' and no extension method 'GetRequestStream' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"